# How to programmatically change name or icon of Eclipse view?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-3.4

Can the name and icon of an Eclipse view be programmatically changed? I am referring to the name and icon that appear in the tab for the view - which are specified as XML attributes "name" and "icon" in the <view> element in plugin.xml.

Answer (score 9):

`setPartName(String)` and `setTitleImage(Image)`, both on `WorkbenchPart` are what you're looking for.

Both `EditorPart`s and `ViewPart` are extensions of `WorkbenchPart`.

It should be noted that both these methods are `protected` so should be called from within the part itself.

Comment: I have tried setTitleImage(null) hoping this would result no icon, but it just displays a default icon. I believe this is contrary to what the documentation says.

Answer (score 0):

setPartName(..) in the ViewPart class.